# Circular Link List program using c

Tags: c

I am just implementing circular linked list program but in this program i am having to face trouble, as you can see I am going to past code below, when I call insertAtLast and isertAtFirst function it's work fine but as soon as I call viewList function to view list item but it shows "there is no items" which I wrote inside if block for run when last is null but in this program I have already inserted two items before viewList call so I think last should not be null because I have already inserted item, I want to print all items of list by viewList function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>`
#include <conio.h>

struct node {

          int item;
          struct node *next;
};
void insertAtFirst(struct node **last, int data) {

          struct node *n, *t;
          n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
          n->item = data;
          t = *last;
          if(*last == NULL) {
                    n->next = n;
                    t = n;
          }
          else {
                    n->next = t->next;
                    t->next = n;
          }
}
void insertAtLast(struct node **last, int data) {

          struct node *n, *t;
          n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
          n->item = data;
          t = *last;
          if(*last == NULL) {
                    n->next = n;
                    t = n;
          }
          else {
                n->next = t->next;
                t->next = n;
                t = n;
          }
}
void viewList(struct node *last) {

          struct node *start;
          if(last == NULL)
                    printf("\n there is no items......");
          else {
                    start = last->next;
                    while(start->next != last->next) {
                              printf("%d  ", start->item);
                              start = start->next;
                    }
          }
}
int main(){

          struct node *last = NULL;
          insertAtLast(&last, 3);
          insertAtFirst(&last, 5);
          viewList(last);

          return 0;
}
```

Comment: `t = n;` should be `*last = n;`

Comment: yeah use *last = n; istead of t = n;   even than i am not able to print list item by viewList function

Comment: thanks , i did it according to your suggestion but i also had to use "do while loop"  instead of "while loop"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `*last = n` instead of `t = n`.

And that's because the latter just causes the variable t to point to n and that's it. But by doing `*last = n` you will at least insert a value in the list even `if last == NULL` I guess that would give the desired output.

Comment: hi , if I use *last = n instead of t = n , i am not able to print list item by viewList Function yet

Comment: thanks , i did it according to your suggestion but i also had to use "do while loop"  instead of "while loop"